# Ubuntu 18.10 kdewallet missing

Tags: kwallet

Since I upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10 (on Wayland) I get a warning on Ubuntu bootup that kdewallet is missing and one of my applications (owncloud) needs it. If I close the warning another warning opens telling me to use another wallet program.

I have looked for kdewallet in Synaptic but it isn't there.However kwalletmanager is there and is installed.

Could someone recommend another wallet to replace kde wallet and how to configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by re-installing kwalletmanager and then running

> kwalletmanager5

in a terminal